# Is there a another way to do this SQL query?

Tags: sql

I'm currently trying to solve a question
But i am not satisfied with the answer given by the source , as i didn't want to use '**IN**' and also i didn't learn **Sub/inner Queries** , but i got the idea
So i thought is there another way ?

[image]

**Question** :

> **Select the names of departments with more than two employees.**

**Answer** :

```
SELECT Name FROM Departments
WHERE Code IN 
( SELECT Department 
  FROM Employees
  GROUP BY Department
  HAVING COUNT(*)      > 2);
```

**What i tried to do is :**

```
SELECT D.name             14
FROOM Employees AS em , Departments AS D
WHERE D.code=em.department AND
( SELECT  department , COUNT(*)  FROM Employees  GROUP BY department ) > 2
```

**I also tried to do this but i think it's wrong:**

```
SELECT  department , Count(*) 
FROM Employees 
WHERE COUNT(*)>2
GROUP BY department
```

**My friend tried to do this but i am pretty sure it's wrong :**

```
SELECT D.Name
FROM employees E INNER JOIN Departments D
ON D.Code=E.Department 
HAVING COUNT(E.Name)>2
```

Comment: What is wrong with the first query?

Comment: Quick thing to learn early on - SQL is a language where you tell the system *what you want*, not *how to do it*. Now, it's possible to overcomplicate things sometimes and confuse the optimizer but it's unlikely that'll happen here. The follow on to the "what you want" comment is that *if two queries express the same logical intent* then (all else being equal), the optimizer should produce exactly the same query plan for both. You don't optimize SQL queries, generally, by avoiding keywords you don't want to use for some reason or other mechanical re-writings.

Comment: The "Answer" query is perfect. You want to select data from the departments table where this is a department with more than 2 employees. Your first query is rather weird. Not only are you using a join syntax that has been deprecated for about thirty years, but why do you join at all? Your subquery returns multiple rows, so it cannot be > 2. One single value can be > 2, not a result consisting of several rows and two columns. Your second query is okay, but you don't select the department name as requested. Your friend's query is almost correct. It is only lacking `GROUP BY d.name`...

Comment: ...But the original "Answer" query is best for its structure clearly separating conditions (which departments do I want to see in `WHERE`) from the selected data (which data do I want to select in `FROM` and `SELECT`).